# Can't capture everyone on the Discord server

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm trying to populate a list of users on a discord server and I can do so on small servers but it seems like when there are over 50 users it doesn't capture everyone.

```
def GuildPop(input): #Make a list of users in the server to check if someone is available.
for member in input.guild.members:
    global member_list
    if any(member.display_name in s for s in member_list):
        return
    else:
        print(member.display_name) #testing print
        member_list.append(member.display_name)
```

Comment: Can you please say why are you using this as a global variable.

Comment: To make a list of users that can be used outside of this method.

Comment: You can do the loop each time you need it instead of this. `for member in guild.members:` Then do whatever you want with that user. Also if you want to do it your name it is better to use `member.id` since it don't change and link it to `guild.id`

Comment: Awesome this helped thanks! I don't know why I was thinking I had to make a list first.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the GuildPop and called the for loop inside of the method that I needed the list for. It works and will cycle through the users on the discord until it finds the specified user. Not sure why it wouldn't populate the list, but I'm also not sure why i was trying to use a list!

```
        for member in message.guild.members:
            print(member.display_name)
            if user2 == member.display_name:
                #do stuff
```